# RESTful WCF service that can respond in both JSON(P) and XML and still be used as SOAP web service?

Tags: wcf, json, rest

Given a contract such as:

```
[ServiceContract] public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData/{id}.{format}")]
    ResponseData GetData(string id, string format);
}
```

Is there a way to get the service to respond with json when requested as:
/GetData/1234.json, xml when requested as /GetData/1234.xml and still be available as a proper soap service at some other url, with a strongly typed wsdl contract?

Using a Stream as the return value for GetData is not workable, as though it fufills the first two requirements, wcf can't create a full wsdl specification as it has no idea what the contents of the resultant Stream will be.

Comment: See [WCF RESTful POX, JSON and SOAP Coexist](http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-restful-pox-json-and-soap-coexist.html) by [codemeit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/11413/codemeit).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *should* have two separate methods which take id and format (and they would call a shared implementation that returns `ResponseData`) which have different [`WebGet` attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData/{id}.{format}.xml", 
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    ResponseData GetDataXml(string id, string format);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData/{id}.{format}.json", 
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ResponseData GetDataJson(string id, string format);
}
```

For the SOAP endpoint, you should be able to call either method, but you are going to have to have a separate [`ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) instance hosting the implementation of the contract.