# WCF: how can we have services in which their output would be serialized by JSON method?

Tags: wcf, web-services, json

wcf: how can we have benefits on using JSON serialization in our services?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question.  What do you mean, "how can we have benefits..."?   do you mean, *what does the server code look like*?  Do you mean *what does the client code look like*?   Do you mean *I have existing service, what do I have to do to use JSON*?  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find some answers and references in [json-or-soap-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237649/json-or-soap-xml).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Json serialization starting from framework 3.5 (use DataContractJsonSerializer).

I think, we have benefits on using all benefits of Json format vs XML.
Of course, wcf service's clients have to support this format :).

Some benefits of JSON :

JSON is well suited to data-interchange than XML.

JSON is much simpler than XML.

JSON messages have less size than the same XML ones, because json is not a document markup language.

JSON is optimized for data.

[more...](http://www.json.org/xml.html)